# Put random values in table from values in a set

Tags: mysql

I want to put random values into my user-table with data from a set.

I got a list of firstnames and surnames and i want to replace all name columns in my table. I was thinking of using a set

```
SET @firstNames = 'Thomas,Chris,Sophia,Ava';
SET @surNames = 'Peterson,Bolander,Travolta,Anniston';
```

Is it possible to write a query which randomly updates values in the **name** column on each user?

Table

```
User table
---------------------
id
name
password
created_at
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you provide the table's structure, some sample input and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Check my updated question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way doing it

```
UPDATE persons 
SET first_name = (
    SELECT val FROM ( 
        SELECT '' as val  
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Thomas' as val
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Chris' as val  
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Sophia' as val 
        ......
    ) AS vals ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

would not be good idea to do that with Mysql, try doing that with your front-end Language. in Mysql we have RAND() function but that returns random number between 0 and 1, it would be very long way to get your desired output with this, so tryout passing random names from your front-end language, which is very easy task

Comment: Its not easy when we are talking about 200.000 records :)